# Direct binding between UI and Model issue within MVVM application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a WPF application with MVVM.As I understood, the main goal of MVVM is to separate between logic layer and UI layer.

I have this Model class :

```
public class User
{
public string Login{get;set;}
public string Pwd{get;set;}
public List<User> GetUsers()
                {
               //
                }
}
```

in my ViewModel, I instanciate a **User** object and an ObservableCollection of **User**

```
  public class UserVM
    {
    public User _User{get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<User> liste{get; private set;}
    public UserVM()
                    {
                    _User = new User("TODO","PWD2");
                    liste = new ObservableCollection(_User.GetUsers);
                    }
    }
```

I feel that I bind directly a UI properties to a model object,So I need To know :

1. When I bind UI properties to the object `_User` properties, did I respect the MVVM architecture?
2. When I bind a listview datasource to `liste`, did I respect the MVVM architecture?
3. For the first question, if it is not suitable for MVVM, is it better to expose the model's properties instead of declaring the class?
4. For the second question, if it is not suitable for MVVM, How can I fix it ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's ok to bind to properties of a model class. You may however need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the model class in order to make the bindings update automatically. I'd also suggest to follow common naming conventions and use CamelCasing (without leading underlines) for property names. `_User` would be `User` (a property name may be identical to the type name), and `liste` would be `UserList` or `Users`.

Comment: @Clemens : Is it normal to bind directly from UI to Model object in MVVM design pattern

Comment: Sure, that is a common practice, as long as the model class provides a property change notification mechanism like INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: but MVVM supose to separate concerns? I mean View can't see the Model and vice versa?

Comment: The view model depends on the model,  typically by subclassing or composition. There is no reason why the view should only use properties of e.g. a derived view model class, but not of the model base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your User class has a tree-like structure in that it contains a List of User objects which themselves may contain a List of User objects...

The problem here is that your view model class contains User objects. Only the UserVM model would contain an ObservableCollection for example.

A simple fix would be: **EDIT** user.GetUsers() doesn't return a `List<UserVM>`

```
public class UserVM
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Pwd { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserVM> Users { get; private set; }
    public UserVM(User user)
    {
        Login = user.Login;
        Pwd = user.Pwd;
        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>(
            user.GetUsers().Select(subUser => new UserViewModel(subUser)));
    }
}
```

You may also want to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that the view gets notifications that the view model has changed.

Comment: Actually this won't work. I'll edit my answer when I've tested my revised solution.

Comment: The caveat to the above code is it makes a complete copy of your model objects when creating the view model. It would be better implemented with lazy loading but that's beyond the scope of this question.